# Cordova video capture - how to get blob data?

Tags: javascript, cordova, video, blob, capture

I'm successfully capturing a video stream with the below code:

```
        navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(

            //...after recorded vid
            function(mediaFiles) {
                var i, path, len;
                for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
                    path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
                    app.f7.alert(path);
                }
            },

            //...couldn't get camera
            function() { app.f7.alert('Sorry - your recording device could not be accessed', 'Error'); },

            //...config
            {limit:2}
        );
```

What I can't figure out is how to grab the blob data of the saved video. I have the filepath to the locally-saved file, but I need to save the data out to a remote server so I need its data.

The success callback is passed a `MediaFile` object encapsulating the captured video, but [the docs don't discuss](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media-capture/#mediafile) any means of getting its raw data. Anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Because **MediaFile** will give you information about the File itself such as

```
name: The name of the file, without path information. (DOMString)
fullPath: The full path of the file, including the name. (DOMString)
type: The file's mime type (DOMString)
lastModifiedDate: The date and time when the file was last modified. (Date)
size: The size of the file, in bytes. (Number)
```

**MediaFileData** will give access to

```
codecs: The actual format of the audio and video content. (DOMString)
bitrate: The average bitrate of the content. The value is zero for images. (Number)
height: The height of the image or video in pixels. The value is zero for audio clips. (Number)
width: The width of the image or video in pixels. The value is zero for audio clips. (Number)
duration: The length of the video or sound clip in seconds. The value is zero for images. (Number)
```

And not the content of the video. If you wanna read its content, load it using MediaFile.fullPath.

To load a video, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327992/cordova-file-plugin-to-load-video-source-from-ios-cache) that might put you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks. "load it using MediaFile.fullPath" - that's precisely what I'm asking how to do. I have the full path, but I don't know how to read the the content of the file the path points to into a blob.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327992/cordova-file-plugin-to-load-video-source-from-ios-cache

Comment: Thanks. I'll investigate that - though the question has no accepted answer and the comments suggest the OP never resolved the issue.

Comment: No joy - the code in that question seems to target different from the one my captured video file lives in. Please see new question - thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716487/cordova-video-capture-how-can-i-save-file-it-out-to-server

Comment: Commented there